# Error loading media: File could not be played error in jw_player rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, jwplayer

I am using the below mentioned code to play a video from my local disk. But its not working instead of that it's throwing Error loading media: File could not be played error error. I have mentioned the code below.

```
 <%= jwplayer_assets %>
 <%= jwplayer ({:file => "/home/user/Downloads/digital.mp4", :image => "/home/user/Downloads/Retreats_21.jpg"}) %>
```

I'am new to this jw_player. so please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Just try with JQuery [JPlayer](http://jplayer.org/).

Comment: i don't know where to write. Please post the sample code as an answer,

Comment: Are you trying to play an uploaded media or just a media from your local disk?

Comment: a media from my local disk

Comment: Can you just show the whole view contents where you are trying to display this media? What is `<%= jwplayer_assets %>`?

Comment: i am using that two lines only which is mentioned in the question. I don't know how to do. so please help me to do.

Comment: Same link: https://github.com/choix/jwplayer-rails/issues/5 posted by VijiKumar.

Comment: he is my friend. we are trying. but didnt get solution yet.

Comment: Hope you have installed `gem 'jwplayer-rails'` gem. and you need to place `<%= jwplayer ({:file => "/home/user/Downloads/digital.mp4", :image => "/home/user/Downloads/Retreats_21.jpg"}) %>` inside a div element. i.e., `<div><%= jwplayer ({:file => "/home/user/Downloads/digital.mp4", :image => "/home/user/Downloads/Retreats_21.jpg"}) %></div>`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51075/discussion-between-rajesh-c-o-and-pooja-agarwal)

Comment: Please check the chat and check the mime-type of the file.

Comment: Can you provide a link to where you are running this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download jwplayer from http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/download/

Put these files to the particular directory:-

- app/assets/jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf
- vendor/assets/javascripts/jwplayer.js
- vendor/assets/javascripts/jwplayer.html5.js

Then add these line in **application.js**

```
//= require jwplayer
//= require jwplayer.html5
```

On the page where you are playing video, add these lines

```
<script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="YOUR_JWPLAYER_KEY";</script>
<div id="video">Loading the player ...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("video").setup({
    flashplayer: "<%=asset_path('jwplayer.flash.swf')%>",
    file: "<%= file_path %>",
    height: 360,
    width: 640,
    analytics: {
        enabled: false,
       cookies: false
   }
});
</script>
```

https://account.longtailvideo.com/#/account from where you can get your **Self-Hosted Player License Key (YOUR_JWPLAYER_KEY)** in signing up from **Get Your License Key** portion.

Take a look https://github.com/shamsulsham89/jwplayer-rails3.2

Please test it first on **Chrome Version 30**

Comment: @Pooja: This answer looks informative and please try this also.

Comment: i tried. its showing the same error Error loading player:
No playable sources found

Comment: Can you provide a link to where you are running this?

Comment: hi. can i add //= require jwplayer
//= require jwplayer.html5 these lines in view page?

Comment: No it should be only added in application.js file