# how to play video from a url in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

suppose I have a youtube video url I want to play it in my rails app with a player how can I do that do any one know any gem to play a video from youtube any dailymotion?

Comment: Why not just pass the URL to the `iframe`?

Comment: It shows the whole page of that video

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23190971/error-loading-media-file-could-not-be-played-error-in-jw-player-rails/23191777#23191777